# Get window width and height, inside init

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using *Python* and *Tkinter*, and I have a function (let's call it getWinProperties) that runs when I initialize my Frame, this function is run after I configure the width and height (e.g. `self.configure(width=width, height=height)`). I need to get the Frames current width and height, to use within the function, this function also needs to be used outside the initialization of the frame.

When I use the `self.winfo_width()` and `self.winfo_height()`, even after `self.update()`, I get given 1 width and 1 height.

```py
class CustomFrame(Frame):

    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.configure(width=width, height=height)
        self.getWinProperties()

    def getWinProperties(self):
        self.update()
        width = self.winfo_width()
        height = self.winfo_height()
        print(width, height)
```

I expected that when initializing the frame, `print(width, height)` would print the width from `__init__(self, width, height)` but instead it printed `1, 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until the window has been drawn on screen it will only have a width and height of 1, since there are many factors that can affect its actual size.

If you want the size it is requesting to be you can use `winfo_reqwidth()` and `winfo_reqheight()`.

From the canonical documenation for the `winfo_width` command:

> Returns a decimal string giving window's width in pixels. When a window is first created its width will be 1 pixel; the width will eventually be changed by a geometry manager to fulfill the window's needs. If you need the true width immediately after creating a widget, invoke update to force the geometry manager to arrange it, or use winfo reqwidth to get the window's requested width instead of its actual width.

Comment: `winfo_reqwidth()` and `winfo_reqheight()` work perfectly, thank you.